# How can I get a coordinate of the top side of a Phaser3 sprite?

Tags: javascript, math, geometry, phaser-framework

I'd like to find out a top coordinate of a snippet. The idea is to make a line between a point and the top of the green element.

How can I find or calculate this coordinate. I know the size of the box and angle.

Here is a [source code](https://github.com/hodovani/plastic-catcher/blob/master/src/Net.js#L16) where I create a purple line.

Here is a gif example.

[image: Game screenshot]

Thanks!

Comment: It is not quite clear what do you want. Rotate net together with rope around top point of the rope like a pendulum?

Comment: @MBo Sorry, yes, you are right. But the rope might change its length. So I can't create a group of the net and the rope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As fas as I understand, rotation center `cx, cy` should be at the top of rope.

Top point of the net has coordinates

```
tx = cx + ropelen * Cos(angle)
ty = cy + ropelen * Sin(angle)
```

If base point of sprite differs from top point,  but lies below by `dy`, you can find its coordinates with the same formula using `ropelen + dy`

If base point of sprite differs from top point,  but lies left by `dx`, you can find its coordinates with the same formula using `sqrt(ropelen^2 + dx^2`) and angle `angle + atan(dx/ropelen)`

Comment: Thanks, I'll check this today.